# using a href to call javascript function with parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net, eval, href

I'm trying to call javascript function from a href . the function has a parameter which will be retrieved by the eval function . But some error occurs .

script:

```
function rate(id) {

            // do something
        }
```

the a tag that will call the function:

```
<a href="javascript:rate(" + <%#Eval("ID")%> + ")" >rate</a>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: What error? Why are you showing us server side code that generates JS instead of the generated JS? Why aren't you using [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) ?

Comment: @JAAulde  the script does execute . If it is <a href="javascript:rate(5)" >rate</a> it executes .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing it like this, but the issue you're currently up against is probably is your quoting/concatenating.

If `<%#Eval("ID")%>` simply produces an INT, this should work:

```
<a href="javascript:rate( <%#Eval("ID")%> )" >rate</a>
```

If it's a string,

```
<a href="javascript:rate( '<%#Eval("ID")%>' )" >rate</a>
```

should do it for you, although you need to handle the case of `<%#Eval("ID")%>` producing anything with a single quote in it.

**A Lesson:**

I say you shouldn't be doing it like this because the javascript pseudo protocol (`javascript:`) is defunct and improper. At worst you should be using an `onclick` which returns false. Ideally you'd  be assigning the event programatically and preventing the event object's default action.

Comment: I wanted to do it programatically, but the problem I face that rate function will call jquery function (plugin for dialog window) . So, is there another way you would suggest ?

Comment: Can you explain, or link to an explanation of why the "best practices" you recommend here are actually superior?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any need for the use of eval() at all.  Code in quotes like this is evaluated at the top level scope.  If you make sure that both rate and ID are defined at that top level scope, then it will work without eval() with this HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="rate(ID);">rate</a>
```

and this code:

```
var ID = 3;

function rate(id) {
    alert(id);
    return(false);
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bqqpM/.  The trick to making this work without eval is just making sure that ID and rate are both available at the top level scope.

Comment: i am using eval, because the a tag is inside a repeater . and to specify which row is this i have to use eval .

Comment: OK, a representative sample of the actual page HTML would be better next time, then we'd know what the overall problem is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `" +  + "`, because it will just be replaced with a number:

```
<a href="javascript:rate(<%#Eval("ID")%>)">rate</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why call it as an href? You can just make a button and style it like a link. That would be a lot easier

```
<button id = "myButton" onclick = "rate(<%#Eval("ID")%>)" >rate</button>

#myButton
{
  border: none;
  padding: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```